# ssh -o PreferredAuthentications: What's the difference between "password" and "keyboard-interactive"?

Tags: ssh, authentication, openssh

Both `PreferredAuthentications=password` and `PreferredAuthentications=keyboard-interactive` would prompt for the password, so what's the difference between them?

I Google'd with the keywords [ssh PreferredAuthentications password keyboard-interactive difference](https://www.google.com/search?q=ssh+PreferredAuthentications+password+keyboard-interactive+difference) but found no answers.

The only difference I noticed is the prompt strings (`user@host's password:` vs. `Password:`):

```
$ ssh -o PreferredAuthentications=password,keyboard-interactive my-host
root@my-host's password:
Password:
Permission denied (gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive).
```

---

#### UPDATE (2018-04-09):

For easy reference, the following is from the [SSH:TDG book](http://www.snailbook.com/) as mentioned in [jouell's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1311829/105590).

> `"keyboard-interactive"` user authentication is intended primarily to accomodate `PAM` authentication on the server side. It provides for a **multiple challenge-response dialog** with the user in which the server sends a text query to the user, the user types in a response, and this process can repeat any number of times. So for example, you might configure `PAM` for SSH with a module which performs authentication using an *RSA security token*, or a *one-time password* scheme. People become confused by this because by default, `"keyboard-interactive"` authentication usually just implements password authentication in a single challenge-response cycle, which just prompts for a password, thus looking exactly the same as `"password"` authentication. If you're not deliberately using both for different purposes, you may want to disable one or the other to avoid end-user confusion.

Comment: See [RFC 4252](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4252) for the *password* auth and [RFC 4256](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4256) for *keyboard-interactive*.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The SSH protocol has numerous authentication methods. The *password* and *keyboard-interactive* are two of them.

The *password* authentication will only ever ask for a single password. There's no specific prompt sent by the server. So it's the client that chooses how to label the prompt (The *"user@host's password"* prompt is from OpenSSH *clients*, like `ssh`, `sftp`, etc).

The *keyboard-interactive* authentication is a more complex request for arbitrary number of pieces of information. For each piece of information the *server* sends the label of the prompt. Moreover it allows the server to provide lenghty description of the overall "form". The server can also specify which inputs are secret (need to be obfuscated when user types them) and which are not.

The latter is often simply used to request a single "secret" password prompt, so you will often find that there is hardly any apparent difference to *password* authentication on the user side.

That's the difference from a protocol perspective.

---

From implementation perspective, with OpenSSH server, the *keyboard-interactive authentication* can be hooked to two-factor (or multi-factor) authentications, e.g. provided by [generic PAM mechanism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluggable_authentication_module) or [Kerberos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerberos_(protocol)).

From a client perspective, another difference is localization. With *password* authentication, clients can localize the *"Password"* label, because they know the server is asking for a password. With *keyboard-interactive* authentication, even when the server is only asking for a single password, clients cannot localize the prompt (unless they employ AI), because it's a generic prompt.

Answer (score 1):

You already know what 'password' is. From a very high level (not brick level protocol stuff) , think of 'keyboard-interactive' as the method that you to use 2FA using Radius and/or SecurID etc. It provides for challenge and response dialogs: [ssh.com](https://www.ssh.com/manuals/server-admin/44/User_Authentication_with_Keyboard-Interactive.html) has a nice short description on it. It goes a steps further to highlight keyboard-interactive is the umbrella which password falls under. Respectfully to the authors, it's bit confusing.

Also see the [Snail Book](http://www.snailbook.com/faq/keyboard-interactive.auto.html) definition. We use this frequently for our RSA protected boxes.