# SSH server asking for password, but PasswordAuthentication is disabled

Tags: linux, openssh, authentication, pam, yubikey

what you will see is the current state of a problem I am trying to solve.
I restarted `sshd` before filling the body this question.

**What I am trying to do:**

- I need to use ssh keys with a yubikey combined to secure authentication to SSH.
- I need to disable clear text passwords.

Relevant parts of my `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` look like this:

```
ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes
UsePAM yes
PasswordAuthentication no
AuthenticationMethods publickey,keyboard-interactive
```

My `/etc/pam.d/sshd` looks like this:

```
# PAM configuration for the Secure Shell service

auth required pam_yubico.so id=16 debug authfile=/etc/authorized_yubikeys

# Standard Un*x authentication.
@include common-auth

# Disallow non-root logins when /etc/nologin exists.
account    required     pam_nologin.so

# Uncomment and edit /etc/security/access.conf if you need to set complex
# access limits that are hard to express in sshd_config.
# account  required     pam_access.so

# Standard Un*x authorization.
@include common-account

# SELinux needs to be the first session rule.  This ensures that any
# lingering context has been cleared.  Without this it is possible that a
# module could execute code in the wrong domain.
session [success=ok ignore=ignore module_unknown=ignore default=bad]        pam_selinux.so close

# Set the loginuid process attribute.
session    required     pam_loginuid.so

# Create a new session keyring.
session    optional     pam_keyinit.so force revoke

# Standard Un*x session setup and teardown.
@include common-session

# Print the message of the day upon successful login.
# This includes a dynamically generated part from /run/motd.dynamic
# and a static (admin-editable) part from /etc/motd.
session    optional     pam_motd.so  motd=/run/motd.dynamic
session    optional     pam_motd.so noupdate

# Print the status of the user's mailbox upon successful login.
session    optional     pam_mail.so standard noenv # [1]

# Set up user limits from /etc/security/limits.conf.
session    required     pam_limits.so

# Read environment variables from /etc/environment and
# /etc/security/pam_env.conf.
session    required     pam_env.so # [1]
# In Debian 4.0 (etch), locale-related environment variables were moved to
# /etc/default/locale, so read that as well.
session    required     pam_env.so user_readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale

# SELinux needs to intervene at login time to ensure that the process starts
# in the proper default security context.  Only sessions which are intended
# to run in the user's context should be run after this.
session [success=ok ignore=ignore module_unknown=ignore default=bad]        pam_selinux.so open

# Standard Un*x password updating.
@include common-password
```

The only row added to `/etc/pam.d/sshd` is:

```
auth required pam_yubico.so id=16 debug authfile=/etc/authorized_yubikeys
```

**Result:**

```
$ ssh test -v
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/dev/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/dev/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for *
debug1: /home/dev/.ssh/config line 5: Applying options for dev
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 9: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to test [192.168.1.2] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/dev/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/dev/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to test:22 as 'admin'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:K2vxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Warning: Permanently added 'test,192.168.1.2' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:mAExxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx /home/dev/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg rsa-sha2-512 blen 535
Authenticated with partial success.
debug1: Authentications that can continue: keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
YubiKey for `admin': 

**Password**

debug1: Authentication succeeded (keyboard-interactive).
Authenticated to test ([192.168.1.2]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
Welcome to Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-112-generic x86_64)

admin@test:~$
```

The login works fine, but can you see the line `**Password**` above?  It shouldn't be asking for it (as it's disabled in the `sshd_config`) and I don't understand why :/

Comment: I think `Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive`, `YubiKey for 'admin':` and `Authentication succeeded (keyboard-interactive)` indicate that this `**Password**` was a *part* of the `keyboard-interactive` method you explicitly requested. `PasswordAuthentication` is related to `AuthenticationMethods password`, not to `keyboard-interactive`. Note `password` and `keyboard-interactive` are [two different things](https://superuser.com/a/894625/432690). I think what YubiKey does is beyond the scope of `sshd_config`. This is not an answer because I don't know how to configure YubiKey or PAM.

Comment: Hi Kamil, thanks for your reply.

I think I figured it out!

I had to comment 

`# Standard Un*x authentication.
#@include common-auth`

To disable Unix password auth. Now it's successfully using the `publickey` and the yubikey response.

Answer (score 4):

I figured it out! I had to comment out

```
# Standard Un*x authentication.
# @include common-auth
```

in `/etc/pam.d/sshd` to disable Un*x password auth.

Now it's successfully authenticating only using the publickey and the yubikey response.