# SSH does not allow password authentication

Tags: linux, ssh, passwords, putty, certificate

I have SSH access to my server using a certificate.
I have configured a user on the same server that would connect using a password, but using Putty, the server only seems to offer certificate login as I get the error:

> "No supported authentication methods available (server sent publickey,
> gssapi-keyex, gssapi-with-mic)"

I did go into `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to enable `PasswordAuthentication yes` and restarted sshd, but that does not seem to do anything.
sshd_config has a line to include separate .conf files, which I have in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/50-redhat.conf`. Here I also added `PasswordAuthentication yes`.

in `/var/log/secure` I find the following:

> May 10 12:42:54 [user] sshd[2053]: Connection closed by authenticating
> user [user] [source-ip] port 60374 [preauth]

Just to be clear: I do not get the chance to put in a password.

Where else should I look to create the possibility of both certificate-based ánd password-based SSH access?

Comment: Care to provide the uncommented sections from your configuration files?

Comment: Or the output of the effective configuration using `sudo sshd -T`

Comment: I was providing the uncommented sections of /etc/ssh/sshd_config, when I found
"PasswordAuthentication no"

That would do it...

Let me try again, and if it still doesn't work, I'll update the question with the requested outputs.

Comment: You seem to have solved the problem by yourself. The right procedure now is as follows: 1. [Write a good answer](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer). 2. [Accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/355310). 3. [Do not announce this fact in the title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116105/355310).

Comment: I am voting to close this question.  The question was caused by a typo or trivial error (not using a configuration that allowed password authentication), which serves the community very little to submit an answer that makes the recommendation actually to enable password authentication.

Answer (score 1):

*Found my answer, leaving it here for posterity.*

Issue seems to be that there are multiple ssh configs now, and not only `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. In my case (ubuntu 22.04) there was a sneaky file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/60-cloudimg-settings.conf` that had a single line `PasswordAuthentication no` that was WREAKING MY LIFE!!!!

Fixed it with this:

```
grep -r PasswordAuthentication /etc/ssh -l | xargs -n 1 sed -i 's/#\s*PasswordAuthentication\s.*$/PasswordAuthentication yes/; s/^PasswordAuthentication\s*no$/PasswordAuthentication yes/'
```

Also, `service ssh restart` was not working, no error, just didn't do anything and needed to use `systemctl restart ssh.service` instead.

Comment: this was there some weeks ago, how the hell did it get there, and what it is (i am on plesk and ubuntu 18 on aws) - anyone any ideas why is it there? didnt use to past few months..

Answer (score -3):

Set KbdInteractiveAuthentication to "yes" in sshd_config and restart. PasswordAuthentication is not enough

Comment: Not true, they are [different, independent methods](https://superuser.com/a/894625/432690). For your information: the OP has solved the problem but neglected to post a proper answer. See the [revision history](https://superuser.com/posts/1783398/revisions) and comments under the question.

Comment: I’ve been posting this answer when I had the problem myself and this was the fix. I hope to save one hour to whoever arrives here after failing trying other solutions. Getting unlikes will just hide one of the possible answers from those needing it.

Comment: `PasswordAuthentication yes` should work, so maybe you have `PasswordAuthentication no` earlier in the file. IMO advising `KbdInteractiveAuthentication yes` because allegedly "PasswordAuthentication is not enough" *without any explanation or insight* is [voodoo](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/V/voodoo-programming.html). "Do this. Period." is not a good answer, it's mediocre *at best*. "Do this. [False statement here]." is worse, even if it "works". The point is we should not promote voodoo. If the answer shows *insight* then I will revoke my downvote.

Comment: Right. There is a teacher for every student. I have limited knowledge about this, so my answer is the best I could provide. 

Ps. i DID have PasswordAuthentication yes and it made no difference, against all readings I could find.