Ubuntu 24.04 LTS: SSH Password Authentication Not Working Despite Configuration Changes
I have the following settings on my Ubuntu server:
sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
PasswordAuthentication yes
KbdInteractiveAuthentication yes

then
sudo systemctl restart ssh.service
However, when a client runs ssh user@server_ip, the server still demands an SSH key and does not ask for a password.
How can I diagnose this issue?
Is there a way to check the actual settings in effect on the server after the restart?
Is there a way to find out why the user cannot use a password?

Do your sshd logs actually show the client as trying to connect to you? That is, are they talking to the right server?

Post the verbose client logs, server logs, and sshd_config file at the time the client was attempting to connect. We only need about 2 minutes of logs.

Found the answer here: https://superuser.com/questions/1783398/ssh-does-not-allow-password-authentication

Though a duplicate, thanks for finding the answer.
